# Placing an iAd banner below a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, iad

I've been trying to get an iAd banner to display at the bottom of my screen using the iAdSuite AdBannerNavigation sample code as a starting point.

The iAd Suite has you create the banner view and add it as a subview.  When you do that to a UITableView the banner kind of floats along atop the cells, moving within the scrollview.

I have seen this answer [iAds in a Scrolling View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442089/problem-with-iad-while-scrooling)
But that method still makes the adbanner a part of the scrollview.

So I thought the simple solution would be to place the UITableView inside a UIView, so that the adBanner could also be a subview to the UIView (a peer to the table view).

```
RootViewController -> TextViewController
                   -> MyTableViewController -> UIView -> UITableView
                                                      -> AdBannerView
```

That didn't work since a UITableViewController expects its first view to be a table view.

Thinking my strategy correct, I pushed the tableview down in the view hierarchy and have it be inited by my view controller.

```
RootViewController -> TextViewController
                   -> MyViewController -> MyTableViewController -> UITableView
                                       -> AdBannerView
```

This is done by the viewDidLoad of MyViewController, where it calls:

```
    myTableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Then, using NSLog statements within MyTableViewController, I'm seeing viewDidLoad gets called but nothing after that.  I was expecting viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, but not only do those NSLog statements never get called, the iOS Simulator never displays my UITableView either (which is reasonable given the situation!).

Am I tackling this the right way (the adBannerView being a peer to the UITableView)?  If so, what am I missing in the view controller and view instantiation process?

My goal in breaking things up into this structure was to have MyViewController know about the iAd banner and keep that separate from the logic of a UITableView (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect article for this. He shows how to add iAd banners to the top of tableviews in both portrait and landscape mode. If you look further down the page, there is also some code that can give you an idea of adding the banner to the bottom of the tableview as well.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

Hope this helps!

Comment: "Unfortunately, it seems like the best way to deal with this situation is to convert your UITableViewController to a normal UIViewController and then proceed similarly to the way we did above" no, no, NO!! Shame on Ray Wenderlich! He should have known to use the table header.